# Can someone explain how Ubuntu manages wallpapers?

Tags: gnome, desktop-background

I am confused about how Ubuntu stores user-selected wallpapers.

I have some pictures I use as wallpapers. We'll call them walla and wallb. Both originate from an encrypted drive that is not automatically mounted. walla is the active wallpaper, but is not in ~/Wallpapers, but wallb is.

So I think "Ok, so Ubuntu must have a place where it copied walla", so to experiment I set wallb.png as the wallpaper and then removed it from ~/Wallpapers. This caused the background to disappear. This left me confused as to where it stored walla, because that encrypted drive I mentioned was not mounted.

Could someone please tell me where Ubuntu stores the active wallpaper and how it goes about deciding when to copy user-provided wallpapers to various destinations?

Comment: did you check in `$HOME/Pictures/Wallpapers` for the copy of walla??

Comment: My ~/Pictures dir is a symlink to a dir on the encrypted drive, so my ~/Pictures dir does not exist until the drive is mounted.

Comment: Active backgrounds are stored in `~/.local/share/backgrounds`. As for how Gnome goes about deciding things ... only a Gnome developer can answer that 

Comment: @matigo That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @mchid only half of one, which is why it's a comment 

Comment: Can't reproduce that in 21.10. The copy is saved under .local/share/backgrounds, deleting the original does not remove that background. On next login, the dconf key is updated to point to the file in the .local/share/backgrounds folder instead of the original.

Comment: I'll start from scratch on Ubuntu 21.10 and reproduce the issue